# Rails: How to find objects that exceed a certain count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to do a query where I want to find Users who have exceed a certain number of violations. In my User model each user `has_many violation`. in my index action I want to find users who have more than 25 violations. This is what I have in my Users controller:

**Update**

```
if params[:viewpage] == "violators"
    @count = "25".to_i
    @users = User.includes(:violation).group('violation.user_id').having("COUNT(*) >= #{@count}").paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
  elsif......
```

This gives me an error: `invalid value for Integer(): "violators"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group` and `having`.

```
User.includes(:violations).group('violations.user_id').having("COUNT(violations.user_id) >= #{@count}")
```

Of course, if you do not have control over the input, then you will want to sanitize the input before you inject into the string.

Comment: Well, we have no idea what `violators` is because you've not defined that anywhere.

Comment: Because your `params[:page]` contains a string of value `violators`, but `paginate` is expecting that value to be an integer.  That `paginate` function needs an integer there to be able to use `limit` and `offset` to build the query.

Comment: Is the table name `violation` or `violations`?  Whichever it is, you need to stay consistent.

Comment: Violations. Changed that and now `PGError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: You'll need to add those fields to the `group` statement.  So it will be `.group('users.id, users.name, violations.user_id, etc...').  You can reduce the number of fields by specifying `select`.  `User.select('users.id, users.name').group('users.id, users.name').having('COUNT(violations.user_id) > #{@count}')`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
@users = User.includes(:violation).where("violations.count >= ?", @count)
```